# The uses of callback or async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, callback

I am trying to understand the use of callback, promise, and `async`/`await`.

The code I pasted below is working fine but I am wondering if it is the best way to present the same meaning in using callbacks, given that callback style might lead to "callback hell", or should I train myself writing all codes using async/await?

```js
// working code:
const loginCheck = (data, callback) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', "login");
  formData.append('mobile', data.mobile);
  formData.append('password', data.password);
  formData.append('region', memberRegion);

  axios.post(API_MIDDLEWARE, formData).then(function(response) {
    callback(response.data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    callback(false);
  });
}
```

Am I correct to use it like this:

```js
const loginCheck = async (data) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', "login");
  formData.append('mobile', data.mobile);
  formData.append('password', data.password);
  formData.append('region', memberRegion);

  await axios.post(API_MIDDLEWARE, formData).then(function(response) {
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

What and how is the best way in order to have the same meaning as the original code using a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as axios is promise based, things are much easier.

First, remove callback, makes no sense in a promise, also if you return a promise and don't need await anywhere else in function, you don't even need to mark a function `async`.

One more thing I would suggest, get rid of code that does -> `.catch(function(error) { console.log(error); }`

So ->

```
const loginCheck = data => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', "login");
  formData.append('mobile', data.mobile);
  formData.append('password', data.password);
  formData.append('region', memberRegion);
  return axios.post(API_MIDDLEWARE, formData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith! I have read the axios doc and realized that axios is promise based, so my original codes using callback writing is actually not necessary right?

Comment: @SmallPotato  Correct, a lot of API's these days are dual purpose.   Often if you don't supply an argument to the callback, it will then return a promise instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
const loginCheck = async (data, callback) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', "login");
  formData.append('mobile', data.mobile);
  formData.append('password', data.password);
  formData.append('region', memberRegion);

  try {  // get to use try/catch if you want
    const response = await axios.post(API_MIDDLEWARE, formData);
    callback(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    callback(false);
  }
}
```

Or:

```
const loginCheck = async (data) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', "login");
  formData.append('mobile', data.mobile);
  formData.append('password', data.password);
  formData.append('region', memberRegion);

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_MIDDLEWARE, formData);
    return response.data;  // return instead of callback
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;  // you can throw
  }
}
```

Then instead of `loginCheck(data, (checked) => { /*use checked*/ })`, you do `const checked = await loginCheck(data)`.

Or you can write:

```
const loginCheck = (data) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', "login");
  formData.append('mobile', data.mobile);
  formData.append('password', data.password);
  formData.append('region', memberRegion);
  return axios.post(API_MIDDLEWARE, formData);
}
```

And use like `try { const checked = await loginCheck(...); } catch (error) { ... }`

Try experimenting with those.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the second way you suggested and it works well too, btw may I ask what is the difference of catch error and throw error?

Comment: @SmallPotato  The throw is there, otherwise the caller of the function wound not know if there was a problem.  In some respects the `catch` logic here is a No Op anyway, makes more sense to leave it out.